# Use Moq to verify if list within object is changed properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I'm trying to add Moq to my tests in MSTest to test parts of my code.

The code i want to test which is not working is a piece of code that should filter data retreived by a service and pass this through. My code is set up through the MVP Pattern and i have the following components. (i'm testing my presenter)

- Service -> this service is retrieving a list of objects and putting this in a model (I'm using a Mock (Moq) to return values)
- Model -> Entity object with some general properties and a list of documents
- View -> The interface my usercontrol is implementing to talk to the presenter. this view is also mocked with moq.
- Presenter -> object to retrieve the model from the service and assign this model to a property of the view.

in my first scenario that is working i just retrieve a model from the service and the presenter passes this to a property of the view.

```
//Setup AccountsPayableService Mock
_mockedDocumentService = new Mock<IDocumentService>();
DocumentModel<InvoiceDocumentRow> model = new DocumentModel<InvoiceDocumentRow>();
List<InvoiceDocumentRow> invoices = new List<InvoiceDocumentRow>();
InvoiceDocumentRow row = new InvoiceDocumentRow();
row.BillingMonth = DateTime.Now;
invoices.Add(row);
model.Documents = invoices;
_mockedDocumentService.Setup(service => service.GetInvoiceDocumentList(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>(), _user)).Returns(model);

//Setup View Mock
_mockedView = new Mock<IInvoicesView>();

//Setup Presenter to be tested
_presenter = new FooPresenter(_mockedDocumentService.Object);
_presenter.SetView(_mockedView.Object);

//Act

//These events will make the presenter do the call to the service and assign this to the view property
_mockedView.Raise(view => view.Init += null, new EventArgs());
_mockedView.Raise(view => view.FirstLoad += null, new EventArgs());

//Assert
_mockedDocumentService.Verify(aps => aps.GetInvoiceDocumentList(from, changedTo, _user), Times.Once());
_mockedView.VerifySet(view => view.DocumentList = model);
```

This test runs and is working perfectly.

however i also have a case where the presenter should filter some of the results it got back from the service and assign a subset to the view. For some reason i can't get this to work.

in essential this is exactly the same test code except a different method on the presenter is used that retrieves data from the service, filters it and then passes it back to the view.

when i do an assert on the view property like i did before:

```
_mockedView.VerifySet(view => view.DocumentList.Documents = filteredModel.Documents);
```

i'm getting an error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression is not a property setter invocation.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: First, one advice. Consider start using inversion of control. Frameworks like Ninject does this: http://code.google.com/p/ninject/. More in: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2008/06/25/NinjectInlineModuleFactoryMethodsProviderSamples.aspx

Comment: We're using inversion of control. just not using any framework in our tests for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem.

I replace the verifySet to a normal assert the _mockedviw.object so i'm using the stub to test instead of the mock and this is working perfectly. to use the stub functionality i used:

```
_mockedView.SetupAllProperties();
```

It's not possible to compare 2 different reference objects by default so i'm just checking the properties manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working cause the filteredModel.Documentos is in another context. Your view doesn't receive this, receive another list that came from some filtering method.

Changing a little your structure I'll suggest create extensions methods and obviously tests to them.
So you can simple put `list.FilterByName("Billy");`

So you will create something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<ObjectFromVdCruijsen> FilteredByNome(this IEnumerable<ObjectFromVdCruijsen> enumerable, string name){
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)){
            enumerable = enumerable.Where(s => s.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(name.ToUpperInvariant()));
    }
    return enumerable;
}
```

Comment: I understand that there are 2 different instances of the models. however i would like it to be able to check if both are equal in my test.